# How to configure proxy for each nginx location of the domain where the request came in

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx

I have successfully configured 2 single WordPress sites with /en(subpath) with Apache

Now I'm trying to configure a staging server.
It is configured as a docker container in the private server as shown below.

```
wordpress1 ▶️ port:40001
wordpress2 ▶️ port:40002
```

In the nginx configuration that you can find below, I'm trying to achieve this:

```
location / ▶️ localhost:40001
location /en ▶️localhost:40002
```

This is my nginx configuration:

user.conf.docker

```
location / {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:40001;

    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect      off;
}

location /en {
    rewrite ^/en(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass          http://localhost:40002;
}
```

The location / works fine.
The location /en only accesses the /en page and causes 500 errors in the rest. I didn't touch the WordPress settings. I also didn't set the apache settings.

wordpress > wp-config.php

```php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/en' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

What more should be set?

Comment: I think the regex part includes the leading "/" after "/en". Let's say the url "/en/home", the result of the rewrite would be `//home`

Comment: @the91end Modify the rewrite rule `rewrite ^/en (.*) $1 break;`then the URL received from Apache is `/home` and it will go to /en/home by the WordPress Apache configuration. If you have anything strange about what I think, please advise.

Comment: This problem seems to be caused by WordPress apache redirection. The configuration of the nginx proxy wasn't wrong.